# Trigger not working as expected

Tags: mysql, triggers

I trying execute an trigger on mysql database.
The command executes successfully, but the trigger not working.

```
DELIMITER #

CREATE TRIGGER generate_coupon AFTER INSERT ON order
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE userid, couponvalue INT;
DECLARE couponcode VARCHAR;
SELECT idUser INTO userid FROM indication WHERE email = NEW.email;
SET couponvalue = 20;
SET couponcode = 'abc123';

INSERT INTO coupon(idUser,idOrder,couponvalue,couponcode) values(userid, NEW.id, couponvalue, couponcode);

END# 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the table name, order, is a keyword. Are you sure the trigger was even created ? I would expect this syntax to fail.

Comment: This syntax is correct, but don't sure if the trigger as added on mysql. Both triggers (mine and eggyal) runs without syntax errors, but after insert on the table, nothing do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem arises from the collisions between your variables `couponvalue` and `couponcode` with the same-named columns in your `coupon` table.  As documented under [Local Variable Scope and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column.

You could simplify your trigger to the following and, in so doing, avoid this problem entirely:

```
CREATE TRIGGER generate_coupon AFTER INSERT ON order FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO coupon
    (idUser, idOrder, couponvalue, couponcode)
  SELECT idUser, NEW.id, 20, 'abc123'
  FROM   indication
  WHERE  email = NEW.email
;
```

Comment: Don't sure if I'm inserting trigger wrongly on database.
I'm using phpmyadmin and execute the code on SQL tab on the database.
The code as executed successfully, but I can't make the trigger work.

After execute the trigger, I try insert a new line on the table 'order'.
The insertion executes successfully, but the table 'coupon' remains empty